# Configuring Cisco ASA 5510 to assign static IP address based on MAC address

Tags: cisco, ip, mac, address

We have a CISCO ASA 5510 at work. We want to configure the same such that it can serve specific IP addresses based on the MAC address of the clients.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

-knd

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it on an ASA.  Not yet, anyway (8.2(2))

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked with routers, but you can do this with IOS on them.  It is called a *static mapping*.  [Here is a link](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t11/feature/guide/gtdhcpsm.html) to the instructions to do it with IOS, maybe they work with the ASA as well?

It works by putting a text file with the mappings on a tftp-server, and telling the router how to get that file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define ARP static table in Cisco ASA,
using Cisco ASDM, on the *Configuration* tab select *Device Managment*, on the tree list go to *Advanced* -> *ARP* -> *ARP Static Table*.
On the right corner you can find the Add button to insert new record [ IP + MAC ].

[image: Cisco ASA ARP static table]

Comment: When I try to do this, it doesn't seem to take effect. I set the association between MAC address and desired IPv4 address in the ARP Static Table page, set the ARP Timeout to 60 seconds, Apply the change, reboot the server I'm trying to change the address of, go to the ASDM DHCP Server Table Page, hit Clear, and then hit Refresh until the machine comes back into the list. The server comes up with a new address, but not the one I specified., and the Server Table page shows that address as associated with an odd MAC address that prepends "01" to the actual MAC address. What am I doing wrong?